# Como dar "trigger" em um Option de um Mat-select que já está selecionado?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Basicamente tenho este `mat-select`:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="form.get('emptyTitle')" placeholder="Nenhum Índice Selecionado"
            (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)">
            <mat-option value="">Nenhum Índice Selecionado</mat-option>
            <div *ngFor="let indice of indices">
                <mat-option [value]="indice._id">{{indice._source.titulo}}</mat-option>
            </div>
        </mat-select>
```

O problema é que eu preciso chamar a função `onSelect` novamente, e obviamente o observador `(selectionChange)` não captura essa seleção, já que é a mesma.

Existe alguma forma de chamar novamente essa seleção que já se encontra selecionada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente não sei o motivo de você querer selecionar algo que ja foi selecionado XD mas vamos lá...

(Se eu entendi sua dúvida) Uma solução simples para o seu problema seria vincular o evento `click` ao `mat-option`

```
<mat-select 
   [formControl]="form.get('emptyTitle')" 
   placeholder="Nenhum Índice Selecionado"
   (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)">
    <mat-option value="">Nenhum Índice Selecionado</mat-option>
    <div *ngFor="let indice of indices">
    <mat-option (click)="selectClick()" [value]="indice._id">
        {{indice._source.titulo}}
    </mat-option>
</div>
```

e no typescript:

```
selectClick() {
    let valorSelecionado = this.form.get('emptyTitle').value;
   // aqui você executa a ação
}
```

Comment: Realmente não pensei nisso, assim que possível eu irei testar, mas provavelmente vai funcionar kkkkk

Comment: Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar :D

Comment: Fiz isso, mas tirei o (selectionChange) para não dar  trigger duas vezes em seleções diferentes kkkk